# Building a tuple to be rendered by a form

Tags: python, django

I have a model `University` which has a field `city`. I'm trying to build a form where the user can select cities or universities. The universities selection is fine:

```
universities = University.objects.all()
university = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=universities)
```

The method I'm trying to get the cities is what is causing me the problem. Here's what I currently have:

```
cities = []
    for uni in universities:
        cities.append(uni.city)
    cities = tuple(cities)

    city_select = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=cities)
```

This gives me the error `too many values to unpack` because the tuple isn't key paired. Is there any easier way to return the choices I've gathered, I feel like I'm going about it in the wrong way. If not, how do I key pair the tuples of cities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple change like below, where each entry in `cities` is a tuple should make this work:

```
cities = []
    for uni in universities:
        cities.append((uni.city, uni.city))
    cities = tuple(cities)

    city_select = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

`MultipleChoiceField` doesn't want a tuple, it wants a queryset. You can use `values_list` to get one with the fields you want:

```
city_select = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=University.objects.values_list('id', 'city'))
```